# DateTimePicker behavior changes in custom CalendarColumn in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I built a test winform project with a custom CalendarColumn in a dataGridView where the datTimePicker looks like this:

[image: first datTimepicker]

When I copied over my form into a larger project the dateTimePicker looks like this:

[image: second dateTimePicker]

The first one works perfectly and I can select any date I like. The second one (the one I need) will not allow me to select today or any previous date.

I have two questions: Why does the second one not let me select any date? Why does it look different?

For reference the Framework for the first is 4.5 and for the second is 4. I changed the framework of the test project of the first one to 4 and it made no difference to it's functionality or appearance.

The custom callendar cell and column code comes from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx - and is unchanged.

The forms are written in VB.NET which I am new to, so probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you copied all relevant code? Do you have a custom control class called `DateTimePicker` defined within your project?

Comment: @GlorinOakenfoot no, there is no custom DateTimePicker class in either project.

Comment: The second image doesn't use visual styles, probably you forget to enable visual styles in the second project.

Comment: Thank you @RezaAghaei - enabling Visual Styles has sorted out the appearance. I am still left though with not being able to select dates in the past.